# Find a key in array of object

Tags: javascript

The input is JSON array of object.

```
[
    {
        "name": "JOHN",
        "age": "90",
        "ID": "123",
        "country": "UK",
        "email": "john@test.com"
    }, {
        "name": "PETER",
        "age": "10",
        "ID": "456",
        "country": "",
    }
]
```

What is the best way in Javascript to find a key in all of the arrays and return ok if it exists. For example, does "name" exist? Yes, JOHN and PETER. Does "email" exist? Yes, john@test.com. Does "city" exist? No.

Thank you for giving tips!

Comment: SO is not an advice forum, we're here to help you fix your code problems. What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Comment: Define "best", there needs to be criteria for evaluation—["*Good, better, best - never let it rest - till your good is better - and your better best.*"](http://www.furphys.com.au/who-we-are/furphy-water-cart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over array, get object's keys, scan for key, return value if found.  Filter your generated array to remove any undefined/false values afterwards (may need revision, depending on your expected values -- especially if you want to include falsy values `{'ID':0}`).

```js
var arr = [{
  "name": "JOHN",
  "age": "90",
  "ID": "123",
  "country": "UK",
  "email": "john@test.com"
}, {
  "name": "PETER",
  "age": "10",
  "ID": "456",
  "country": ""
}];

var key = 'name';
var values = arr.map(obj => ~Object.keys(obj).indexOf(key) && obj[key]).filter(v => v);

console.log(values)
```

Without writing a book, here are some clues to what's going on:

- `map` iterates over the array and generates a new array using the mapping function
- `~` bitwise NOT, performs `-(N+1)`, which is useful when working with `indexOf()` because a non-match would return `-1`, but the NOT operator translates `-1` to `0` (false); 
  Math: `-(-1+1)=-(0)=0`
- [more on bitwise NOT] 
  When `indexOf` matches it returns `0`(or greater).  Using the `-(N+1)` mentioned above, this means `~` operator converts any match to a negative number, which is truthy.  `-(0+1)=-1` or `-(3+1)=-4` -- all truthy
- If the `~...indexOf()` is true the logical AND operator (`&&`) will perform the second expression, which retrieves the value from the object and returns it
- `Object.keys()` gets the keys of the object
- `filter()` iterates over an array and only keeps elements that the match function returns true
- `v=>v` is the match function, which is equivalent to `function(v){ return v; }`, meaning if `v` is truthy, keep the value; if falsy, don't keep the value in the array (similar to `grep` of other languages)

---

Edit:
As [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) pointed out, in place of the `~[].indexOf()`, `[].includes()` can now be used, making the code look something like `Object.keys(obj).includes(key)`.  This should remove some of the less understood operators (for beginners) as well as make the code more semantic and readable.

Comment: I feel like `arr.map(obj => ~Object.keys(obj).indexOf(key) && obj[key]).filter(v => v);` is going to be ridiculously confusing for a beginner. I don't even know what it means and I've worked with JS a lot.

Comment: @Clonkex check if that helps you ;)

Comment: Instead of `~Object.keys(obj).indexOf(key)` it is more semantic to use the fairly new [*includes*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.includes) method: `Object.keys(obj).includes(key)`. It will also not return properties whose value evaluates to false (e.g. `"age": 0`), which is a bug I think.

Comment: @RobG correct -- added an update.  Regarding the *bug*, no, that was intentional I tried to mention it in the intro description, which talks about the filter and then again in the last bullet point, which talks about the match function `if falsy, don't keep the value in the array`.  More many usecases this may be good enough, but the idea is the OP can now see how to do something and learn more about refining it.  I think there should be a general disclaimer: ***No code should be copy/pasted into production code, without first understanding what it does***

Answer (score 2):

if you like a magic-oneliner:

```
your_array = [
    {
        "name": "JOHN",
        "age": "90",
        "ID": "123",
        "country": "UK",
        "email": "john@test.com"
    }, {
        "name": "PETER",
        "age": "10",
        "ID": "456",
        "country": "",
    }
]

your_array.some(x => 'email' in x)
your_array.some(x => 'name' in x)
your_array.some(x => 'city' in x)
```

Comment: Simple and fits the requirement. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr=[
          {
              "name": "JOHN",
              "age": "90",
              "ID": "123",
              "country": "UK",
              "email": "john@test.com"
          }, {
              "name": "PETER",
              "age": "10",
              "ID": "456",
              "country": "",
          }
        ];
var fu=function(arr,prop){ 
   return $.map(arr,(v,k)=>{if(v.hasOwnProperty(prop)){return arr[k][prop]}});
}
console.log(fu(arr,"ID"));
console.log(fu(arr,"name"));
console.log(fu(arr,"email"));
```

Comment: You were doing really well until `$.map(...)`. [*Array.prototype.map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) has been around since ECMA-262 ed 5.1, so no reason to use a library unless IE 8 is in your basket of browsers to support (and there is a [*pollyfil*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control#Polyfill) for that).